# PowerShell seems to be returning an array but it does not

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops

I am executing the following command

```
az acr repository show-tags
```

and the result I get is

```
[
  "1",
  "2",
  "latest"
]
```

when I assign the result to a variable and do a check type I get `Object[]`.

```
PS> Write-Host " $($tags.GetType())";
System.Object[]
```

then when I do a `for` loop I get an exception

> Cannot index into a null array.

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $tags.length; $i++) {
    $tag = $array[$i]
}
```

Since the return type is not empty and is an array why cant I loop the array?

Comment: Array(I) should be tags(I)

Comment: Where do you define `$array`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do

```
foreach ($tag in $tags) {
    write-host $tag
}
```

to loop through the array? In your example there is no array called $array so it errors as it is a null object.

Sorry if I have missed what you are trying to do, hopefully this helps.